# Are there connotations of subtotals in the phrase "add up the total"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, connotation

Does the phrase "add up the total" typically have a connotation that, from the list of all the numbers being added, there are some particular subtotals that either have already been calculated or at least could in principle be calculated?

Or is the phrase often used in cases where there are no meaningful subtotals that one could be interested in calculating from the list of numbers?

Comment: Are you trying to use 'add up the total' and are concerned about meanings that people will infer wrongly, or are you reading and wonder what the author meant?

Comment: 'Add up the total' **is** a rather unexpected expression. The DO of 'add up' usually refers to the constituent parts (add up these numbers / add up all the payments you've made'. 'Add up the total' means 'Work out the total by doing the necessary addition calculations'. But there is no requirement that there are necessary or significant subtotals among the numbers being added. Artificially, there usually are: many people would total 17 + 55 + 83 via the subtotal 100.

Comment: Did you intend to write "add up the total**s**" (plural)?

Comment: @Tom22 'Unexpected' in the sense that it's a usage quite distinct from the usual 'Add up these figures / those numbers / these costs / the numbers attending ...'. The expression 'add up the total' is very common.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As a veteran of the Accountancy profession I would say the word that is missing here is "grand total", which is the alternative measure to "sub-total", or "sub-sub-total". If there are no existing sub-totals in a list, there is no point in using "grand total". You can just ask "what's the total?" But when sub-totals appear, to make oneself clear, one needs to ask "What's the grand total?".

Comment: 6 months later and I still have misgivings about the question (I must have deleted a prior comment @EdwinAshworth referred to). I definitely get that others might see it differently, but still, if the goal is clarity and some find it unclear, a comment saying so is helpful. To me: "to total" and "to add up" are synonyms - although 'total' a bit more prone to have a negative number in the list perhaps. "A total" to me is similar to "a sum". "add up the totals"(plural) would imply multiple lists or categories . I find the singular strange and redundant vs Total up, or "find the total" feel OK

Comment: @Tom22 But that's opinion. There are 6.5 million Google hits for "add up the total"; admittedly, many use 'total' as a modifier ('... total cost / total number of / total mass') but the DOs almost always seem to refer to the end result rather than starting elements or subtotals.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth   The three words as a segement of something longer..  sure? 
 "add up the total area of the four figures"  .   Also, used in a sorta sloppy way like "Add up the total from these two columns"  ( this should be 'totals of the two columns"  OR "add up all the entries from these two columns",  but yes, this short hand would be understood even if poor grammar for saying "total these two columns then add those together "  maybe?  -  "add up the total of these two columns might just be "total up the two columns" and not at add them together  too? ambiguous)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I think it is a bad question as it is not really a "phrase" but a  segment of multiple phrases that might be used differently and generally probably not used correctly in some of the ways speculated about ... but we would be correcting words that weren't there ?  If the question had an ENTIRE sentence, then we could address what it meant within that sentence.  (or explain differences if multiple sentences were given)

Comment: Again, opinion. 'Boil a kettle' doesn't really hold water logically, but it's totally acceptable. Usage, not what individuals might want (unless they can muster enough of them), ultimately defines acceptability. And a lot of people use 'add up the total'.

Answer (score 2):

Totals and subtotals are independent; one does not require the other, since they are operations involving lists. You can sum up the entire list or just a portion.